# Like Button Not Showing Counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This happens on any web browser. When I go to the page, I see the like button not showing any counts. Then I...

1. Press on the Like button.
2. I then see the box say +1.
3. I refresh the page.
4. I no longer see the +1 and I see the Like button as if it was never pressed.

I can repeat steps 1-4 endlessly with the same results - I never see the total live count.

It would seem like it's not keeping counts, but when I query it via:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count from link_stat where url='https://www.myswebsite.com/'&format=json

I see the live stats - so I know it's working. I've also tried different variations of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - and old versions as well. I've isolated the code to just be the facebook code with nothing else on the page. For some reason, when I use https://www.myswebsite.com/ it doesn't show. I try other URLs like http://www.google.com with the code, and it works fine, I can see the count.

It's an SSL web site. Does this have anything to do with it? Also, when we initially launched the site with the Like button, it was http://mywebsite.com originally. Then we switched it to http://www.myswebsite.com, and then setup a SSL wildcard to function with both. I'm not sure if caching has anything to do with it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having exactly this same problem (not counting but working, on a SSL website). Did you find any solution in the end?

Comment: I'm having the exact problem. When i query through fql it shows the correct number, but in the page the button shows nothing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This [blog](http://www.allwebmaster.com/2011/07/fix-facebook-like-button-not-working/) post might give you some help. What the post says is that you can "sort of" clean your URL with Facebook URL linter tool

Also there is a bug reported related to this [issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706)